# What should we use here?

Tags: british-english

Which one I should use and why?

> There are being fewer jobs for young people these days.
>
> There are fewer jobs for young people these days.

Personally, I think I should use first one because of the phrase *these days*, meaning temporary period.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot use the verb *to be* in a continuous sense in most cases. Yes, there are some idiomatic expressions where this isn’t true, but this example sentence isn’t among them. So the second is the correct version.

Answer (score -1):

The second one is correct. Not sure why, but will update answer when I can articulate it.

> There are being fewer jobs for young people these days.
>
> There are fewer jobs for young people these days.